# Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition does not exist in C# application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use Cortana in a windows store app but I keep getting the error:

> The type name or namespace 'SpeechRecognition' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Windows.Media' (Are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am running Windows Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. To create the project I clicked `File->New->Project then selected "Blank App" from "Templates"->"Visual C#"->"Windows Store"`. I checked the References in the Solution Explorer and it says all framework assemblies are already referenced.

I have .NET Framework 4 and .NET Framework 2.0 installed.

I'm following the two guides from `MSDN` but I can't figure out why this namespace is missing:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Universal-Windows-App-Development-with-Cortana-and-the-Speech-SDK/03
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630430.aspx

I've never used C# before but I've done C++ and C. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I haven't been able to find a solution through google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selected a template for a Windows Store app, but Cortana and [Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.aspx) are available only for Windows Phone. Window Store apps run on Windows desktops, laptops, and tablets (see [What's a Windows Runtime app?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn726767.aspx))

If you have Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later then you should have a template for Visual C#/Store Apps/Windows Phone Apps/Blank App (Windows Phone) which will support Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.

You can download the upgrade to Update 4 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921 if you don't have it.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm playing around with the Windows 10 technical preview which has Cortana enabled. Is there not a way to use Cortana in a windows 10 store app yet?

Comment: Windows 10 SDKs have not yet been released.